# How to display validation errors from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, routes

My customers#show action has a form on it for creating messages (a customer has_many messages).

When the form gets submitted, it goes to messages#create. I have a validation that the 'text' column of message must not be blank, and the validation works. However, I'm not sure how to render the customers#show again with the validation errors displayed. I've tried a few things and it seems to either redirect_to but loses the validation errors or render 'customers#show' but it actually goes to /messages instead of /customers/:id. here's my code:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @customer = Customer.new
    end

  def show
    @customer = current_user.customers.find(params[:id])
    @messages = @customer.messages
    @message = Message.new
  end

class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.new(
      customer_id: params[:message][:customer_id],
      text:        params[:message][:text],
      direction:   'sent'
      )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to customer_path(params[:message][:customer_id]) }
        format.json { render json: @message, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render template: 'customers/show' }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

this currently renders the customers/show but on the wrong route (should be /customers/:id rather than /messages). How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flash`

```
def create
    @message = current_user.messages.new(
      customer_id: params[:message][:customer_id],
      text:        params[:message][:text],
      direction:   'sent'
      )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to customer_path(params[:message][:customer_id]) }
        format.json { render json: @message, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        flash[:error] = @message.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
        format.html { render template: 'customers/show' }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And in your show view, you can display the error using

```
<%= flash[:error] %>
```

You can also call errors directly from the @messages object since you are only rendering the view and not redirecting

```
   <%= @message.errors.full_messages.join("\n") %>
```

Comment: Yes but the issue is also that rendering doesn't really work for me since it goes to /messages instead of /customers/:id. Then I don't have any instances ready for my form. Is there a way to make render work to render the correct route? Alternatively, can I use redirect_to and keep @message?

Comment: You can use redirect_to and use flash

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It's not the best solutions since I can't have the @message validation errors in line with the input fields but since I only have one error that can occur, I guess it's ok. Thanks!